# Java Pool Hibernate c3p0

Tags: java, hibernate, threadpool, c3p0

Caros, boa tarde.

Tenho uma solução Java que está gerando problemas em Produção, derrubando o banco.
Após algumas alterações, configurei um pool utilizando hibernate c3p0 para gerenciar o número de sessões abertas (máximo em 100). A aplicação respeita o pool.
Acontece que o método implementado é falho: há uma fila que gerencia o envio de mensagens  e, a cada nova mensagem, uma nova sessão é aberta para o envio de uma única mensagem.

Minha dúvida: possível estabelecer uma única sessão por usuário, para realizar várias transações para o envio da mensagem? E quando houver transbordo para essas transações, abrir uma
nova sessão por usuário? Na configuração atual são abertas 100 sessões, que não são fechadas e travam o envio de novas mensagens.

**cfg.xml**

```
<bean id="oracleSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordC3P0ConnectionProvider" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.encryptor_registered_name" value="configurationHibernateEncryptor" />      
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${jdbc.connection.driver_class}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.url" value="${jdbc.connection.url}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.username" value="${jdbc.connection.username}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.password" value="${jdbc.connection.password}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${jdbc.dialect}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${jdbc.hbm2ddl.auto}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="${jdbc.show_sql}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="${jdbc.format_sql}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="${jdbc.use_sql_comments}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="${jdbc.generate_statistics}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
            <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="30" />
            <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.max_idle_time" value="10"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="30" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**ClASSE**

```
public void sendMessage(String msg) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    Transaction transaction = null;
    Session session = null;     

    try {   

        session = this.getSession();        
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        
        HibernateDAO dao = new HibernateDAO(session);
        Message message = null;
        try {
            MessageJsonSerializer serializer = new MessageJsonSerializer();
            message = serializer.deserialize(msg);

            MessageSender sender = new MessageSender(dao, this.serviceConnectorFactory, this.jmsSender,
                    new MessageSenderListener(dao, this.jmsSender));
            sender.sendNowAssync(message);

        } catch (MessageBrokerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 

        } finally {
            if (message != null) {
                PersistentMessage p = dao.findPersistentMessage(message.getId());

            }
        
        }

        transaction.commit();

    } finally {
        if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        
    }

}
```